# Jquery if hover element add a button if not remove button

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover, mousehover

I am adding a button in jquery with append, bot I got 2 problems

1- keeps adding this button everytime I hover.

2 -when is not hover the button still there.

```
$('#user tbody tr td').hover(function() {
   $(this).addClass('hover2').append('<button>add user</button>');
}, function() {
 $(this).removeClass('hover2').remove('<button>add user</button>');
});
```

Comment: Please add your html code

Comment: Why not create the `<button>` in HTML and simply show and hide it using css' `:hover` pseudo-class? This has some advantage in that you're not having to reattach event-handlers to the newly-created element every time it's recreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#user tbody tr td').hover(function() {
   $(this).addClass('hover2').append('<button>add user</button>');
}, function() {
 $(this).removeClass('hover2').find('button').remove();
});
```

sample using `<div>` element

http://jsfiddle.net/xtb51wed/1095/

Answer (score 2):

Use mouseenter/mouseleave events

```
$('#user tbody tr td').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).addClass('hover2').append('<button>add user</button>');
}).mouseleave(function() {
 $(this).removeClass('hover2').find('button').remove();
});
```

demo:

```js
$('#user tbody tr td').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).addClass('hover2').append('<button>add user</button>');
}).mouseleave(function() {
 $(this).removeClass('hover2').find('button').remove();
});
```

```css
.hover2 {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="user"><tbody><tr><td>mouse</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you adding and what you removing is not matched. You should somehow find the element you added before and remove it.

```
$('#user tbody tr td').hover(function() {
   $(this).addClass('hover2').append('<button>add user</button>');
}, function() {
 $(this).removeClass('hover2').find('button').remove();
});
```